# Prevent a link from working if user is not logged in

Tags: jquery, wordpress, preventdefault, nextgen-gallery

I have a Wordpress site which has a gallery on a page visible to all users.

The idea is that if a non-member clicks a gallery thumbnail, they get redirected to a signup page. If a user *is* logged in, the image displays in a lightbox as usual.

I'm playing with this jQuery code and can't get the preventDefault bit working - I think it's because it's inside a conditional.

```
$('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail a').on('click', function(event){

        if (!$('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
            alert('Not logged in!');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Also I'm pretty sure there'll be a more secure way of doing this using PHP - if anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be most grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
$('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!$('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
        alert('Not logged in!');
        return false;
    }
    $(this).addClass('lightbox');
});
```

Dont give the lightbox class before,first check for the condition and then if it satisfies then add class for the lightbox

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gautam, I can see what you had in mind there but for some reason the lightbox still pops up after the Alert is closed.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to look into a different approach as this needs to affect a lot more links site-wide.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format of `on()` method is this:

```
$('.ngg-gallery-thumbnail').on('click', 'a', function(){
    if (!$('body').hasClass('logged-in')) {
        alert('Not logged in!');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Also, there's no need of `preventDefault()` method here, since you are using `return false` here.

Returning `false` performs three tasks when called:

1. event.preventDefault();
2. event.stopPropagation();
3. Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Palash, however it still loads the lightbox after the Alert has fired.